# C++ won't let me make friends

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two classes, Mesh and MeshList.  I want MeshList to have a function that can change the private members of Mesh.  But it won't compile and I don't know why.  Here's my code.

**Mesh.h**

```
#ifndef _MESH_H
#define _MESH_H

#include "MeshList.h"
#include <iostream>

class Mesh
{
private:
    unsigned int vboHandle_;
    friend void MeshList::UpdateVBOHandle();
public:
    inline void Out() {std::cout << vboHandle_;}
};
#endif
```

**Mesh.cpp**

```
#include "Mesh.h"
```

**MeshList.h**

```
#ifndef _MESH_LIST_H
#define _MESH_LIST_H

#include "Mesh.h"


class MeshList
{

public:
    Mesh *mesh; //Line 11 Error
    void UpdateVBOHandle();
};
#endif
```

**MeshList.cpp**

```
#include "MeshList.h"

void MeshList::UpdateVBOHandle()
{
    *mesh->vboHandle_ = 4;
}
```

I get these errors:

MeshList.h (Line 11)

- error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
- error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
  support default-int
- error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
  support default-int
- mesh.h(11) : error C2653: 'MeshList' : is not a class or namespace
  name
- meshlist.cpp(5) : error C2248: 'Mesh::vboHandle_' : cannot access
  private member declared in class 'Mesh'
- mesh.h(10) : see declaration of 'Mesh::vboHandle_'
- mesh.h(8) : see declaration of 'Mesh'
- meshlist.cpp(5) : error C2100: illegal indirection

Comment: You need to get out more.

Comment: Try `class Meshlist;` instead of `#include "MeshList.h"`

Comment: @Matthieu: a brief glance says it's a really good start though.

Comment: @MooingDuck: yes it is, however because the OP tries to befriend only a single method of `MeshList` a forward declaration does not cut it.

Comment: I didn't even read this question before I upvoted @BenjaminLindley's comment, and now I'm trapped by '+1 for the title alone'.

Comment: This was made exclusively for the title, you cheater.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cyclic dependencies are explained in the other answers...

Here comes the solution:

In `MeshList.h`:

- replace `#include "Mesh.h"` with the forward declaration `class Mesh;` (You don't need the include here, because you only declare a pointer to a Mesh)

In `MeshList.cpp`:

- add `#include "Mesh.h"` to your includes (you need the declaration, because you use the Mesh)

The last compile error, you mentioned is another problem:

```
*mesh->vboHandle_ = 4;
```

`mesh` is a pointer. Your code selects the member `vboHandle_` and tries to dereference it (which fails). I suppose you mean:

```
mesh->vboHandle_ = 4; // <-- no leading asterisk
```

Comment: Fixed the answer according to David's comment.

Answer (score 9):

When you compile `Mesh.cpp`, it includes `Mesh.h`, which includes `MeshList.h`, which starts to include `Mesh.h` but stops early because `_MESH_H` is now defined. Then (back in `MeshList.h`) there's a reference to `Mesh` -- but that hasn't been declared yet. Hence, e.g., your C2143 error.

Comment: @ildjarn, that's interesting as I've never discovered that anywhere. May I ask why?

Comment: @chris : You'd have to ask the people who designed C++!

Comment: @ildjarn: Are you sure? I am actually quite sure that the opposite is true. I even think to remember that the standard stated that befriending a class was equivalent to befriending all its functions... I'll have to look for the quote I guess.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I removed the #include "MeshList.h" from Mesh.h, but that just gives me the error MeshList is not a class or namespace.

Comment: @David : Indeed, it seems it is legal, at least according to VC++ 2010 and [GCC](http://ideone.com/kAVaG). Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @ildjarn 11.3p5 *When a friend declaration refers to an overloaded name or operator, only the function specified by the parameter types becomes a friend. A member function of a class X can be a friend of a class Y.*

Comment: @Legion: You have a cyclic dependency, which are usually code smells. At any rate, if you really feel that this makes sense in your design, what you need to do is *forward declare* the `Mesh` before the definition of `MeshList` (that does not need a full definition of the type) and then include the Mesh header only in the .cpp.

Answer (score 6):

It's because you've `#include "MeshList.h"` in the file `Mesh.h`, so the file `MeshList.h` will be compiled first, and the class `Mesh` is not yet declared. For that the compiler will think that `Mesh` in the error line is a variable name that has not got a type before it, hence the error.

This is an example of making a `friend` member function:

```
#include <iostream>


class foo;

class bar
{
public:
    void barfunc(foo &f);
};

class foo
{
private:
    friend void bar::barfunc(foo &f);
    int i;
public:
    foo()
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    void printi()
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
};

void bar::barfunc(foo &f)
{
    f.i = 5;
}


int main()
{
    foo f;
    bar b;
    b.barfunc(f);
    f.printi();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**The problem:** Cyclic dependencies in your includes. The error message is less than ideal, unfortunately.

---

**The solution:** If you befriend the whole class, instead of a single function, then you can use a forward declaration of the class to break the cycle.

```
// Mesh.h
#ifndef _MESH_H
#define _MESH_H

#include <iostream>

class MeshList;

class Mesh
{
private:
    unsigned int vboHandle_;
    friend class MeshList;
public:
    inline void Out() {std::cout << vboHandle_;}
};
#endif
```

---

Some (subjective) guidelines:

- Include stuff in reverse order of your ability to change it if it breaks, that is: STL first, 3rd party headers second, your own middleware stack third, the current project includes fourth and the current library includes fifth. This way, if there is a conflict, hopefully the error will point to a header of yours.
- Put the `public` stuff before the `private` stuff in a class. Clients of the class are only concerned with the public interface, no need to have them wade through all the dirty implementation details before they can get to it.

Comment: As I understand, you don't need forward declaration if your friend declaration is above the first usage. (I've tested similar example w/o 'class MeshList;' in VS and it workes.)

Comment: @anxieux: I never really fully understood in which scope the name after `friend class` was injected if it could not be found; so I've taken the habit of just forward declaring the type. Slightly more verbose, perhaps, but hey: it works 100% of the time!